# Как передать значение в callback функцию

Tags: javascript

Как передать значение `i` в function чтобы после того как пришел результат для конкретной итерации можна было сохранить результат для конкретного запроса?

```
var points = [];
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    $.get('do-get', {apikey: 'key', values: points[i].join('|')}, function (data) {
        result[i] = data; // ответы приходят в ином порядке чем уходят запросы
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

так?

```
var points = [];
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
        $.get('do-get', {apikey: 'key', values: points[i].join('|')}, function (data) {
            result[i] = data; 
        });
    })(i);
}
```

---

Кстати, итоговый `result` все равно нужно будет где-то просматривать и работать. По очевидным причинам после цикла никак этого сделать нельзя, потому что запросы `ajax` асинхронные... Выхода из этого может быть несколько, от глупых, до еще более глупых))

- Например внутри `callback` проверять чему равно `i` и если оно равно `points.length` работать с финальным массивом:

  ```
  ...
  ...
  $.get('do-get', {apikey: 'key', values: points[i].join('|')}, function (data) {
      result[i] = data; 
      if (i == points.length)
          finalFunction(result);
  });
  ...
  ...

  function finalFunction(resArr) {
      console.log("тут работа с result ");
  }
  ```
- Может быть сделать массив `ajax` запросов и воспользоваться функцией **[jQuery.when()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_deferred)**, с помощью которой можно дождаться выполнения всех асинхронных запросов. Пример:

  ```
  var points = [];
  var result = [];

  var ajaxArr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) { 
      ajaxArr[i] = ajaxFunction(i);
  }

  $.when(...ajaxArr).done(function(...test){
      // в test будут все запросы по всем ajaxArr
      console.log(test);

      // запихнем в result данные
      for (var el in test) {
          result.push(test[el][0]);
      }    

      console.log(result);
  });

  function ajaxFunction(i) {    
      return $.ajax({
          url: "do-get",
          method: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          data:  {apikey: 'key', values: points[i].join('|')}        
      });
  }
  ```
- Может быть не стоит это делать в цикле?

Answer (score 1):

А еще должно работать с `let`

```
var points = [];
var result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    $.get('do-get', {apikey: 'key', values: points[i].join('|')}, function (data) {
        result[i] = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: э-э-э, "Это - вряд ли." Товарищ Сухов

Comment: @Igor И тем не менее https://jsfiddle.net/dmhx65gj/

Comment: @Igor да вроде все правильно. `let` должен решать проблему. хотя работать с итоговым массивом все равно нельзя вне цикла

Comment: ok, withdrawn, +1